# Group rows of data by column value then store nested data, first and last occurrences, and counts within each group

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach, grouping

I am trying to split an array of space-delimited strings, group by a particular column, then store the data within each group in a more convenient structure.

Sample data:

```
$dataArray = [
    0 => "AAAAA 2023 01 25 01:04:00 ID:20fjrjeZZ",
    1 => "AAAAA 2023 01 25 01:18:08 ID:13454B43A",
    2 => "AAAAA 2023 01 25 02:00:02 ID:18f5hjeWe",
    3 => "AAAAA 2023 01 25 04:10:13 ID:13454B43A",
    4 => "BBBBB 2023 01 25 01:44:10 ID:Xj74320fj",
    5 => "BBBBB 2023 01 25 07:08:58 ID:13454B43A",
    6 => "BBBBB 2023 01 25 08:40:52 ID:Ftzkk800Y",
    7 => "BBBBB 2023 01 25 14:10:13 ID:18f5hjeWe"
];
```

I split the rows on the space with:

```
$lines = explode(' ', $dataArray);
```

Then I want to push the individual parts (AAAA, 2023, 01, ...) into an array.

```
foreach($dataArray as $parts){
    $spotArray[] = $parts[$parts][0];
    $yearArray[] = $parts[$parts][1];
    // ...
}
```

Then build a new structure with the new array parts:

```
foreach($dataArray as $key => $value){
    $desiredArray[] = $spotArray[["user"[$yearArray[$hourArray]]], "first"[/** ... */]];
    //...
}
```

Expected result:

```
$desiredArray = [
    "AAAAA" => [
        "user" => [
            "ID:20fjrjeZZ" => ["01:04:00"],
            "ID:13454B43A" => ["01:18:08", "04:10:12"],
            "ID:18f5hjeWe" => ["02:00:02"]
        ],
        "first" => "01:04:00",
        "last" => "04:10:12",
        "totaUser" => 3,
        "totalAccess" => 4
    ],
    "BBBBB" => [
        "user" => [
            "ID:Xj74320fj" => ["01:44:10"],
            "ID:13454B43A" => ["07:08:58"],
            "ID:Ftzkk800Y" => ["08:40:52"],
            "ID:18f5hjeWe" => ["14:10:13"]
        ],
        "first" => "01:44:10",
        "last" => "14:10:13",
        "totaUser" => 4,
        "totalAccess" => 4
    ]
];
```

Comment: `$spotArray[["user"[$yearArray[$hourArray]]], "first"[...]];` - makes no sense syntax-wise. `"user"[...]` makes little sense here, this would try to access the individual characters in the text literal `user` with whatever `...` currently is as the index. `$yearArray[$hourArray]` also makes no sense, when `$hourArray` itself is an array, that will only result in an "Illegal offset type" error.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/o3OAB check also my answer as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not at all necessary to run two loops.

Parse the space-delimited strings in your array and build/overwrite/sum as you iterate.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/uBRLG))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($dataArray as $row) {
    [$group, $y, $m, $d, $t, $id] = explode(' ', $row);
    $result[$group]['user'][$id][] = $t;  // accumulate nested elements
    $result[$group]['first'] ??= $t; // only store the first occurrence
    $result[$group]['last'] = $t; // keep overwriting each time
    $result[$group]['totaluser'] = count($result[$group]['user']); // count what is accumulated
    $result[$group]['totalAccess'] = ($result[$group]['totalAccess'] ?? 0) + 1; // increment
}
var_export($result);
```

---

You can even safely remove the unused `$y`, `$m`, and `$d` declarations if you wish. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/N798U))

Output (from either snippet)

```
array (
  'AAAAA' => 
  array (
    'user' => 
    array (
      'ID:20fjrjeZZ' => 
      array (
        0 => '01:04:00',
      ),
      'ID:13454B43A' => 
      array (
        0 => '01:18:08',
        1 => '04:10:13',
      ),
      'ID:18f5hjeWe' => 
      array (
        0 => '02:00:02',
      ),
    ),
    'first' => '01:04:00',
    'last' => '04:10:13',
    'totaluser' => 3,
    'totalAccess' => 4,
  ),
  'BBBBB' => 
  array (
    'user' => 
    array (
      'ID:Xj74320fj' => 
      array (
        0 => '01:44:10',
      ),
      'ID:13454B43A' => 
      array (
        0 => '07:08:58',
      ),
      'ID:Ftzkk800Y' => 
      array (
        0 => '08:40:52',
      ),
      'ID:18f5hjeWe' => 
      array (
        0 => '14:10:13',
      ),
    ),
    'first' => '01:44:10',
    'last' => '14:10:13',
    'totaluser' => 4,
    'totalAccess' => 4,
  ),
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your example solution. There is an error on the demo page. And I see that the user times are not listed. "ID:13454B43A" => ["01:18:08", "04:10:12"]

Answer (score 1):

You can find the answer to your question here

```
<?php

$dataArray = [
        0 => "AAAAA 2023 01 25 01:04:00 ID:20fjrjeZZ",
        1 => "AAAAA 2023 01 25 01:18:08 ID:13454B43A",
        2 => "AAAAA 2023 01 25 02:00:02 ID:18f5hjeWe",
        3 => "AAAAA 2023 01 25 04:10:13 ID:13454B43A",
        4 => "BBBBB 2023 01 25 01:44:10 ID:Xj74320fj",
        5 => "BBBBB 2023 01 25 07:08:58 ID:13454B43A",
        6 => "BBBBB 2023 01 25 08:40:52 ID:Ftzkk800Y",
        7 => "BBBBB 2023 01 25 14:10:13 ID:18f5hjeWe"
    ];
    
$finalArr = array();
$count_arr = array();
$count_arr1 = array();
foreach($dataArray as $parts){    
    $lines = explode(' ', $parts);
    $finalArr[$lines[0]]['user'][$lines[5]][] = $lines[4];
    $count_arr1[$lines[0]]['user'][$lines[5]] = $lines[4];
    $count_arr[$lines[0]][] = 1;

}
foreach($finalArr as $key => $parts){   
    $finalArr[$key]['first'] = reset($count_arr1[$key]['user']);
    $finalArr[$key]['last'] = end($count_arr1[$key]['user']);
    $finalArr[$key]['totaUser'] = count($finalArr[$key]['user']);
    $finalArr[$key]['totalAccess'] = count($count_arr[$key]);
}
print_r($finalArr);
```

Comment: This seems to be a correct solution. However, could you explain it a bit more for the OP? I know it's pretty straight forward, but now he/she might not now what are all the things you did :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and your code. I see that the user times are not listed. ```"ID:13454B43A" => ["01:18:08", "04:10:12"]```

Comment: @CemFirat i  have update answers..  https://3v4l.org/c9mQc